# Getting 'no provider for service' when i declare it inside constructor

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

**Brief Explanation:**  I have created a service `commopen.ts`, I have imported it in my `page.ts` and also added in providers, code is shown below -

```
import { Commopen } from './commopen';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-givencommunicationclosed',
  templateUrl: 'givencommunicationclosed.html',
  providers: [Commopen]
})
export class GivencommunicationclosedPage implements OnInit {
  public loggedinuser;phone;SNO;

  //public _coopen:Commopen;
  constructor( public _coopen:Commopen,......
```

When I declare `public _coopen:Commopen` inside `constructor` I get below error when page is opened in browser:

[image]

If I declare `public _coopen:Commopen;` outside constructor, there is no error, why?

I have created and used many services till today, but unable to find the reason for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the provider to the NgModule, i.e module.ts under providers,

```
providers: [
  Commopen
]
```

Comment: added, but for all other services it was never required, after adding on clicking the page its saying `no provider for navController`

Comment: you need to add whatever services inside providers otherwise you cant use them .now you need to add navController

Comment: app.module.ts showing error now , been 5 hours unable to deal with it

Comment: can i use team viewer with you ?

Comment: yeah, but not now :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161176/discussion-between-user2828442-and-sajeetharan).